# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12/31/'

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
declare @StartDate date
declare @EndDate date

set @StartDate='09/01/2016'
set @EndDate='11/30/2016'

SELECT 
    1 AS Segment,
    'C' AS Subsegment,
    100 AS Ent,
    'KPAR' AS LOB,
    'ATLB' AS Cov,
    ClaimNumber AS [Claim#],
    '12/31/'+AccidentYear AS AYDate,
    convert(date, cast(AccountingPeriodDate as date),101) AS EvalDate
```

However I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12/31/' to data type int.

I haven't gotten this error before, and was wondering it it's due to a datatype change.

Comment: I'm assuming `AccidentYear` is an int. so it's trying to add 12/31/ to that column. Look at using `CONCAT()` or cast AccidentYear as a varchar

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use ISO standard date formats, such as YYYYMMDD and YYYY-MM-DD.

Then, be explicit about the conversion and use `try_convert()`.  So, I would write this as:

```
select try_convert(date, concat(accident_year, '1231'))
```

`concat()` will automatically convert the number to a date.

Or, alternatively, use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(accident_year, 12, 31)
```

This is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably need to cast accidentyear as varchar

```
 DECLARE @accidentyear AS INT
 SET @accidentyear = 2016

 SELECT '12/31/' + CAST(@accidentyear AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT 1 AS Segment
        ,'C' AS Subsegment
        ,100 AS Ent
        ,'KPAR' AS LOB
        ,'ATLB' AS Cov
        ,ClaimNumber AS [Claim#]
        ,'12/31/'+ CAST(AccidentYear as nvarchar(4)) AS AYDate
        ,convert(date, cast(AccountingPeriodDate as date),101) AS EvalDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The advice you got from other users to cast/convert accidentYear to varchar is correct.  The reason this is necessary is because the data types are not the same.  '12/31' is clearly a string.  We also know that AccidentYear is an int because the error message says it's an int.

Since the data types are different, SQL Server attempts an implicit data type conversion.  When SQL Server does this, the string is converted to an integer and then math is performed on it.

Since implicit conversion is not possible, you need to use explicit conversion instead.  By using the cast or convert function, you are doing an explicit conversion.

The rules for implicit data type conversions can be found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396